# How do I add a link into an HTML5 Video after a frame?

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video which I wish to display a link on.  When I click said link the video will jump X number of frames further into the video.  Would this be possible using a JavaScript library such as JQuery?

Comment: Hello!  As this is your first question I'd like to explain what you should do now.  Take a look at any answers you have received and try to fix your problem!  Also make sure that if you find a solution that works, mark it with the tick so that other people know how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is most certainly possible.  It is essential you place this JavaScript code in your project:

```
 var myvideo = document.createElement('yourvideoid');
 var curtime = video.currentTime;
```

This creates two variables which hold the video element and the video time.  After you have done that I suggest you take a look at [this](https://dev.opera.com/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-html5-video-audio/) article from dev.opera.com.

In case you need to skip to a specific time on the video. here's what you have to do:

```
var mylinkbt= document.getElementById('mylinkid');
mylinkbt.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.currentTime = 7 /* your time here */;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);
```